# Google Cloud No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, microservices

I created a REST API and uploaded it to Google Cloud. When I try to access from another domain, it gives the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://35.198.15.248:8080/api/clientes/pf/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Then I added the following class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 

public class ConfiguracaoDeCors extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("POST, GET, HEAD, DELETE, UPDATE")
            .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "Authorization")
            .allowCredentials(false)
            .maxAge(32400);
  }
}
```

And the error continues.
Could anyone help?

ADD:

Its working

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLICOS).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: The error description in title differs from the one in the body of your question (**In 'Acc...** vs **No 'Acc...**) Is it intended?

Answer (score 1):

Using the CrossOrigin annotation provided by spring might be helpful in your case:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

If your configuring via GlobalConfiguration, the snippet below might be helpful as well.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following annotation in the controller class methods you want to allow cross-origin requests.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods = { RequestMethod.POST }, allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{order}/details", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Order getOrderDetail(@PathVariable Long order, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
//...
}
```

In this example, all requests to `/123456/details` will allow cross origin for POST method. In your configuration, you're allowing CORS to all requests and that is not a good practice.